# Odoo: Action Error Could not find client action on (Odoo 9 / Open ERP)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I have been working on developing a simple Odoo 9 plugin utilizing QWeb, and I have run into in issue where I am unable to successfully able to register/call an action from a .js file no matter what I do.

The purpose of this simple app is simply to create a menu item, with a link that invokes an action. The menu creates successfully, but every time I attempt to invoke the action, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

The Javascript file attempts to register an action entitled `test.DoSomething` using the following code:

```
openerp.test = function(instance, local) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
    _lt = instance.web._lt;

    instance.web.client_actions.add('test.DoSomething', 'instance.test.DoSomething');
    instance.test.DoSomething = instance.web.Widget.extend({
        start: function() {
            console.log("Doing Something!!!!");
        }
    });
}
```

This is referenced from a `test.xml` file containing the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="test" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/testapp/static/src/js/test.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>

        <menuitem id="main_testapp_menu" name="Test App" />

        <menuitem id="testapp_menu" name="Test App"
        parent="main_testapp_menu" />

        <record id="action_home_page" model="ir.actions.client">
            <field name="name">Test Home Page</field>
            <field name="tag">test.DoSomething</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="home_page_menu" name="Home Page" parent="testapp_menu"
        action="action_home_page"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

The `__openerp__.py` file contains this:

```
{
    'name' : 'testapp',
    'version': '1.0',
    'summary': 'testapp',
    'category': 'Tools',
    'author': 'Test',
    'description':
        """
TEST APP
====================

Simple test application for odoo
        """,
    'data': [
        'test.xml' 
    ],
    'depends' : ['web'],
    'application': True,
}
```

Is there a newer/different way to register actions in Odoo 9? Even trying example code from Odoo 8 generates similar errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see any mistake within presented code, it should work in Odoo 8, only if there is no module name mismatch:

Take look of the first line in SJ: `openerp.test = function(instance, local) {` here module name is important, so you have to take it into the account. You cannot write `openerp.whatever = function(instance, local)`, you should use `openerp.an_exact_technical_name_of_your_module = function(instance, local)` in order to have your JS code executed by Odoo.

The name you should use as `an_exact_technical_name_of_your_module` is a technical name of your module (i.e. name of main directory of your Odoo module), maybe it isn't `test` in your case? ( maybe `testapp` or something? ), so use the correct name instead of `test` and it should be fixed then.

If you align name and your code is not executed anyway, than it should mean that Odoo has changed JS definitions in Odoo version 9 without backward compatibility in mind, then you'll be required to write the entire JS code in a new style, that is in the `odoo.define('an_exact_technical_name_of_your_module.some_feature', function (require) {` style... for example please refer to some JS code in Odoo 9 source code, for example [this one](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/account/static/src/js/account_reconciliation_widgets.js), although you might get expression that everything is changed, actually changes are quite superficial and you can still depend somehow on current documentation for internal implementation of Widgets in JS  ([Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/web.html) has not been  aligned yet to the changes in core source code), but more general things, like add/register new features to Odoo, you'd better to consider to look for examples in the Odoo sources (like the one I [referenced](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/account/static/src/js/account_reconciliation_widgets.js) above)

Comment: That definitely solved my issue. Once I changed the name of the javascript module name to match the overall module name then it worked. Thanks!